# How to get iphone device token for push notification?

Tags: iphone, notifications, push

I am trying to use Remote Push Notification in my app, and I was trying to have this test out within my app, but i couldn't reset the alert popup after i tap on "Allow" at the very beginning.

**so my question is:**

Do i still get the device token even when the user tap "Don't Allow" in the alert popup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use appDelegate method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
    {
        self.mDeviceToken = deviceToken;

        //Removing the brackets from the device token
        NSString *tokenString = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];

        NSLog(@"Push Notification tokenstring is %@",tokenString);

    }
```

and in case error

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSString* s=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",error];
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:s delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [s release];
// lert because your device will not show log
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following delegates method...

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{

    NSLog(@">>%@",deviceToken);// this will give  you token
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@">>%@",error); // this will gave you error msg with description.

}
```

Hope, this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken

{

    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);

}
```

In this way you get iPhone device token